# Double-negation deduction rule in https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Tags: logic, deduction

How can we use double-negation deduction rule?
For example, ~~p is the same as p.

I am not able to find how to eliminate ~~ in https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: The rule is DNE and it is listed on the right of the screen: Derived Rules.

Comment: Is that all you're having trouble with? **Kristian Berry** saves the day with her answer, complete with illustrations, *pro bono*. In the 22nd century?! Am I dreaming mon ami?

Comment: Fantastic. I was trying to put ~~E. Now, it is clear.

Comment: Is there a double-not introduction rule? Something like DNI?

For example, p is equivalent to ~~p, without going throug p, ~p, contradiction, and then not not p

Answer (score 2):

Note that they have DNE in their sidebar:

[image]

So, click CREATE PROBLEM, put ~~A on line 1 and A for the conclusion. Then click NEW LINE, put A in the first box, then put "DNE, 1" in the box to the right. Click CHECK PROOF.

[image]

Now, this may provide the answer to your question, and the Philosophy SE might be about analyzing arguments logically and all, but your issue seems to be a software consideration, not a philosophical one, so please don't accept my answer even if it's sufficient, I don't think I've earned the points for that. (Moreover, then, the OP question is liable to be closed/deleted anyway, so it wouldn't do me any good to get the points, aye?)